# Getting correct value of num_rows back AJAX/JSON

Tags: php, json, ajax, mysqli, polling

I have a notification system that out puts the right value of 1 and updates the div accordingly when a user posts one on my wall.

```
{
    "num":1,
    "notification_id":"640",
    "notification_content":"Lucy  Botham posted a status on your wall",
    "notification_throughurl":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=515",
    "notification_triggeredby":"85",
    "notification_status":"1"
}
```

But if a user posts twice it does nothing and doesn't update at all.

```
{
    "num":1,
    "notification_id":"641",
    "notification_content":"Lucy  Botham posted a status on your wall",
    "notification_throughurl":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=516",
    "notification_triggeredby":"85",
    "notification_status":"1"
}
{
    "num":1,
    "notification_id":"642",
    "notification_content":"Lucy  Botham posted a status on your wall",
    "notification_throughurl":"singlepoststreamitem.php?streamitem_id=517",
    "notification_triggeredby":"85",
    "notification_status":"1"
}
```

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
$user1_id=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
$call="select MAX(notification_id) AS notification_id ,notification_status,notification_targetuser,notification_triggeredby,notification_throughurl from notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id' AND notification_status='1'";
$chant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));


while($notification=mysqli_fetch_array($chant)){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var notification_id="<?php echo $notification['notification_id']?>";
var notification_targetuser="<?php echo $notification['notification_targetuser']?>";
var notification_triggeredby="<?php echo $notification['notification_triggeredby']?>";
function loadIt() {

$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_id="+notification_id+"&notification_targetuser="+notification_targetuser+"&notification_triggeredby="+notification_triggeredby,   
dataType:"json",
success: function(data){
if(data.notification_stream=1){
 $("#notif_ui"+notification_id).prepend('<div class="notif_text"><div id="notif_actual_text-" class="notif_actual_text"><img border="1" src="userimages/cropped'+data['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg" onerror=this.src="userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg" width="40" height="40" ><br /><a href="'+data['notification_throughurl']+'">'+data['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+data['notification_time']+'<br/></div></div></div><hr/>');

 i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+data.num)); 

    if(!data.notification_id.length) {
   //no results...
   return;
}
notification_id = data.notification_id; 
}
}
});
}
setInterval(loadIt, 10000);   
 </script>
<? } ?>
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
$json = array();
$com=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * from notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$idw' AND notification_triggeredby='$ide'  AND notification_status='1' ORDER BY notification_id")or die($mysqli);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($com)){


$num = mysqli_num_rows($com);
if($num){
    $json['num'] = 1;
}else{
    $json['num'] = 0;
}
$json['notification_id'] = $row['notification_id'];
$json['notification_content'] = $row['notification_content'];
$json['notification_throughurl'] = $row['notification_throughurl'];
$json['notification_triggeredby'] = $row['notification_triggeredby'];
$json['notification_status'] = $row['notification_status'];


echo json_encode($json);
}}
$sql  = "UPDATE notifications SET notification_status = '2' WHERE notification_targetuser='$idw'";
$go = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: I would highly recommend fixing indentation and commenting the code so that others have an easier time helping.

Comment: You say it "does nothing" but below that you have what looks like output from the server?

Answer (score 1):

You're echoing the JSON results inside a loop, so if the loop executes more than once, the final result is not valid JSON data. It's just multiple chunks of JSON.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($com)){
    $id = $row['notification_id'];
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($com);
    if($num){
        $json['num'] = 1;
    }else{
        $json['num'] = 0;
    }
    $json[$id]['notification_id'] = $row['notification_id'];
    $json[$id]['notification_content'] = $row['notification_content'];
    $json[$id]['notification_throughurl'] = $row['notification_throughurl'];
    $json[$id]['notification_triggeredby'] = $row['notification_triggeredby'];
    $json[$id]['notification_status'] = $row['notification_status'];
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Then you'll need to adjust your Javascript to expect an array instead of a flat object.

Comment: May I ask how I'd expect the array as I'm not familiar with it. Thank you

Comment: Just loop through it with a `foreach` or the Javascript equivalent thereof. Another question to ask yourself is, do you want to be returning multiple rows or just single notifications?

Comment: I'd like more than 1 if there is more than one. :D

Comment: Ok then, instead of JS expecting `data->notification_content` you'll have to make a loop to look for `data[0]->notification_content`, `data[1]->notification_content`, etc.

Comment: TBH. I'm lost already. Could you maybe mock an example up please so I can get visual confirmation haha

Comment: Looping over an array is pretty basic stuff. I'm not up on Javascript syntax, spend most of my time on the server side.